# Datalist is not working in ie9, code done by angular?

Tags: angularjs, html

Here using datalist i did autocomplete in angulaer, But its not working in ie9.
other than ie9 its working good,

even i tried like giving like this

```
<datalist id="associates">
 <!--[if IE 9]><select disabled style="display:none"><![endif]-->
   <option ng-repeat="a in availableTags" value="{{a}}">
 <!--[if IE 9]></select><![endif]-->
 </datalist>
```

**HTML**

```
 <datalist id="associates" >
                <option ng-repeat="a in availableTags" value="{{a}}">
 </datalist>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
 $scope.availableTags = [
"Manoji (12345)",
"Roshan(32136)",
"Divya(789565)",
"Ankur(852369)",
"Manju(251425)",
];


$scope.addedAssociates = [];
$scope.addAssociate = function(b){
    if($scope.addedAssociates.indexOf(b) == -1){
        $scope.addedAssociates.push(b);         
    }
}
```

Can any one suggest me solution for this, any hacks for working from ie9+?

Comment: What version of Angular are you using?

Comment: license AngularJS v1.2.16 @Nicholas Smith

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't added the polyfill to your page, that could be your problem.

According to this, datalist doesn't work in IE9.

http://caniuse.com/#feat=datalist

But can be made to work with this polyfill:

http://css-tricks.com/relevant-dropdowns-polyfill-for-datalist/

Comment: If i use modenizer will it support in ie9?

Comment: I think you'll still need a polyfill for datalist.  See this article discussing how to get it working with modernizr: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/html5-datalist/